# NTFS / windows partitions disappeared after updating Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: installation, grub2, partitioning, ntfs

I updated Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 from the live CD downloaded and then on restart I didn't have anymore the Windows line in the Grub menu and then while in Ubuntu I couldn't find my other partitions at all. Actually, now the old partitions are gone and I have just one big Ubuntu partition. I don't care about the windows, but I need the data from my second NTFS partition that I had.
Can someone help me to recover that (to restore the old partitions)?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Run the "Disk Utility" application to determine if you still have your Windows partition. If you do, then this page is your friend: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Answer (score 0):

that sounds like you've installed OS across all of your hard drive, when installing there are options like to choose how and where to install, you should read the cautions before clicking `next`. Here's one solution that might help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery